# ASM stack frame allocation size difference

Tags: assembly, stack, size, frame, allocation

Currently, I'm reading the book '*An assembly language introduction to computer architecture using the intel pentium*' by Karen Miller.

Firstly, the explanation of *call* and *ret* are given, which explain the saving of the return adress. 
Secondly, the difference between a leaf and non-leaf procedure is explained: a leaf procedure does not call anything else, whereas a non-leaf procedure does. This leaves 1 dword (32bits) less space to be used for the rest of the stack frame:

> This return address is considered part of the frame for the procedure. The first doubleword within the frame is the return address. For a non-leaf procedure, the amount of space allocated for the remainder of the frame is one doubleword fewer than the size of the frame, since the *call* instruction allocates (and uses) space for the return address.

After that, a code example is given, which brings me to my main question.

```
A: sub ESP, 20 ; allocate frame for A
               ; return address is at [ESP+20] in A's frame
   call B
   call C
   add ESP, 20 ; deallocate A's frame
   ret

B: sub ESP, 20 ; allocate frame for B
               ; return address is at [ESP+20] in B's frame
   call D
   add ESP, 20 ; deallocate B's frame
   ret

C: sub ESP, 12 ; allocate frame for C
   ; unnecessary cope of C's return address is at [ESP+12]
   add ESP, 12 ; deallocate C's frame
   ret

D: sub ESP, 20 ; allocate frame for D
               ; return address is at [ESP+20] in D's frame
   call D
   add ESP, 20 ; deallocate D's frame
   ret

E: sub ESP, 12 ; allocate frame for E
   ; unnecessary cope of E's return address is at [ESP+12]
   add ESP, 12 ; deallocate E's frame
   ret
```

Procedure C and E are both leaf procedures, since they do not call anything. Why do these leaf procedures only get 12 bits (correct me if I'm wrong there as well) whilst the non-leaf procedures get 20 bits(?)?

Comment: That's bytes and makes no sense to me.

Comment: Likely these code pieces are invented to implement something described later in the book, or they was got from a higher-level compiler output without proper rethinking. I hope the first variant is true, but in this case you should read the whole book before deciding on its quality.

Comment: A compiler could use `SUB ESP, something` to allocate space for local variables and/or properly align the stack pointer according to some convention. In pure assembly you set the convention and can do whatever you like. No idea where the numbers 12 and 20 come from. I would ignore this and try the next chapter.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I think the replies answer my question in total. I'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A compiler could use SUB ESP, something to allocate space for local
>   variables and/or properly align the stack pointer according to some
>   convention. In pure assembly you set the convention and can do
>   whatever you like. No idea where the numbers 12 and 20 come from. I
>   would ignore this and try the next chapter.

By Bo Persson

> Likely these code pieces are invented to implement something described
>   later in the book, or they was got from a higher-level compiler output
>   without proper rethinking. I hope the first variant is true, but in
>   this case you should read the whole book before deciding on its
>   quality

By Netch

> That's bytes and makes no sense to me.

By Jester